# Communication with Zebra RFID Printer | C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, usb, communication, zebra-printers

We are developing an application which prints RFID labels using Zebra RZ400 RFID printer. Until now, we were sending ZPL commands by [RawPrinterHelper](http://code.google.com/p/carlitox/source/browse/trunk/+carlitox+--username+matako/CarlitoxDelivery/Helper/RawPrinterHelper.cs?spec=svn3&r=3) class which makes call to winspool.drv.

However, we soon realized that not all tags are printed successfully so we looked for a way to get feedback about the success of the last print operation. There is a command "^RV" that is said to return a string upon a print operation that reflects operation success result.

Now, the problem is we don't know a way to get this feedback data from printer! RawPrinterHelper class does not have any method to get data.

I connected the printer to USB and used LibUsbDotNet library to communicate with the printer. I can send commands to printer successfully including "^RV" command and read from USB again to get the feedback from printer. I can get the feedback value but not every time, only once after randomly printing lots of tags.

Is there an offical SDK from Zebra to communicate with printers? What can be wrong about USB communication? Please share your experiences regarding Zebra .NET development.

Answer (score 2):

There is an official [Java SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html) which does bi-di communications to the printer using the Windows driver (for USB. It does direct for Tcp). There is also a [Windows Mobile SDK from Zebra](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/adapt-software/zebralink-sdk-windows-mobile.html) which ***might*** work for you.

You can try dropping in the dlls, and then take a look at the `UsbPrinterConnection` class.  Lemme know if it works for you

Comment: I am getting an exception with the message "Unable to find an entry point named 'ZebraOpenUsb' in DLL 'ZebraUsb.dll'."

Comment: Are all your DLLs in the same directory? Did you grab all of them from the Zebra SDK?

Comment: Yep, all ZSDK_API.dll, ZebraUsb.dll, ZebraPlatformUtil.dll ZebraBluetoothAdapter.dll are in the same project and bin directory. I downloaded the SDK from Zebra.

Comment: Hmmm weird error... Well, it was worth a shot! That SDK was for winMo, never really tried it on PC.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, I got mail from a Zebra employee saying there is no SDK for .NET at the moment. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

TCP/IP Bidirectional Programming Example Using Sockets - C#
https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA140&actp=LIST

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was directed by a Zebra employee to the same link but our printer does not have an Ethernet card installed, so TCP/IP communication is not possible for us. If you have any other code snippet that demonstrates USB communication, I will be glad.