# How to encode RFID label for Zebra Printer using C# and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, rfid, zebra-printers

**Problem**

I am using Visual Studio, C#, and .NET. I am also using ZPL commands to print hello world to a Zebra ZD500R. I have been currently unsuccessful in figuring out how to encode an RFID label using the above. I know a SDK for java exists, but my environment is a strict Microsoft stack.

The RFID label that is printed has VOID printed on the entire label. Something like VOIDVOIDVOIDVOIDVOIDVOID. I have included the updated code below.

**Code**

Here is the following code I have currently written after studying Zebra documentation and sample code:

```
  public static void PrintLabels()
        {
            try
            {

                string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
                int port = 1337;

                // ZPL Command(s)
                string ZPLString =
                "CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~" +
                "^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR4,4~SD10^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ" +
                "^XA" +
                "^MMT" +
                "^PW300" +
                "^LL0526" +
                "^LS0" +
                "^FT267,433^A0I,42,40^FH\\^FDHello World^FS" +
                "^RS8" +
                "^RFW,H^FD1234^FS" +
                "^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ";  






                // Open connection
                System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
                client.Connect(ipAddress, port);

                // Write ZPL String to connection
                System.IO.StreamWriter writer =
                new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                writer.Write(ZPLString);
                writer.Flush();

                // Close Connection
                writer.Close();
                client.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is a rudimentary example, but does the trick by printing hello world. As far as I know, I was thinking the RFID encoding aspect should be a new line in the string ZPLString. Unfortunately, when I looked into the Zebra programming book I did not see any ZPL commands to confirm this thought.

**Attempts**

I have done the following in an attempt to solve this problem.

- RTFM for Zebra ZPL found [here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)
- Downloaded the Zebra Label designer. No encoding function found.
- Browsed the ZPL sample code.
- Checked stack overflow for relevant questions. Closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610260/communication-with-zebra-rfid-printer-c-sharp-net) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775701/verify-encoding-tags-by-zebra-printer-rz400), but still not my use case.

Any advice, tips, or comments would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes -

Check out page 381 (table 18) for a list of commands compatible with that printer.

Pages 400 and 401 contain some writing examples. The first one is:

```
^XA
^RS8
^RFW,A^FD00 my data^FS
^XZ
```

Let's dissect this. ^XA (start) and ^XZ (end). Plus two others: ^RS and ^RF.

^RS – Set Up RFID Parameters

> ```
> UHF Printers
> 0 = None
> 1 = EPC Class 0
> 2 = EPC Class 0 Plus
> 3 = EPC Class 1 64-bit
> 4 = EPC Class 1 96-bit
> 5 = UCODE EPC 1.19
> 6 = Impinj Class 0 Plus
> 7 = ISO 18000-06A
> 8 = EPC Class 1, Generation 2 (Gen 2)
> 9 = ISO 18000-06B
> ```

Not sure which transponder you're using. Adjust accordingly.

Then there's ^RF: Read or Write RFID Format.
In this example, they're doing a write operation in ASCII (^RFW,A)

Next, we see

```
^FD00 my data^FS
```

Which is the begin and end marker for data.

---

Another example, this time writing hex:

```
^XA
^RFW,H^FD1234^FS
^XZ
```

You see the `,H` used, instead of `,A`. Again, we see ^FD and ^FS delimiting data.

---

**In Summary...**

I'm guessing that you want something like this (let's assume you're writing hex):

```
^XA
^FO10,10
^A0,100,150
^FDHello, World!^FS
^RS8
^RFW,H^FD1234^FS
^XZ
```

So, in c#:

```
string ZPLString = "^XA^FO10,10^A0,100,150^FDHello, World!^FS^RS8^RFW,H^FD1234^FS^XZ";
```

You MAY need to throw in a `^RS` and go off of the above chart.
When sending the command string, you don't need to add in any extra line feeds or CR's.

std_disclaimer: I have only used ZPL to print, not for RFID encoding. Make sure that you have the correct transponders for this unit. According to docs, it supports tags compatible with UHF EPC Gen 2 V1.2/ 
ISO 18000-6C.

I would test out your ZPL using Zebra's utilities first. If it works, then start playing in c#. Just trying to limit the number of variables at play ;)

Comment: I will be using UHF EPC Gen 2 (ISO 18000-6C). Given you code, all I can understand is that it is saying it is RF write, hex, data is 1234. I am confused at to where we set up RFID parameters in the ZPL code?

Comment: What are you going to actually write to the tag?

Comment: For the RFID, an inventory tracking id number. On the tag itself, hello world works for now, but eventually probably the id number and the name of what we are tracking.

Comment: I added the extra line in, to init for EPC Gen2. It's the same as their example (^RS8).

Comment: You are awesome. I will read the pages you mentioned and then code on this. I think it will work, and if it does I will mark yours as the answer. I bow in humble thanks for your assistance thus far. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Good luck! Be sure to give me an update either way ;) RFID stuff is a lot of fun, but I mostly play with MiFare (ISO 14443A) and Tag-It (ISO 15693).Have fun :)

Comment: BTW - the big thing to take out of this (at least, I'm willing to bet money) is that the commands to print and encode are sent together - all in one request.

Comment: I have not been able to verify RFID encoding yet. I ran into this problem: http://bit.ly/1Mfrj2v on my way. Once I can print text on a label as intended, I feel comfortable with using the approach with above. Can you please help?